# Somatório de grupos em um SQL

Tags: postgresql, query

Preciso fazer o somatório TOTAL por secretaria de um campo de horas que está no formato decimal, além disso, realizar a conversão dele.

Consigo realizar o somatório dos funcionários, mas não consigo somar por "grupos" de secretaria.
Ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com meu SQL ele traz que o funcionário 1233 tem 20 horas e o funcionário 4123 tem 8 horas. Mas não é isso que preciso. Preciso que o somatório seja feito em cima das secretarias. 
Secretaria 10, 30 horas. Secretaria 7, 8 horas.

Estou um pouco perdido na montagem dessa query.

Cheguei até esse ponto e estou travado. Segue abaixo minha query:

```
SELECT
    S1.id,S1.cd_secretaria,
    to_char(to_timestamp(sum((S2.nr_horas) * 60)), 'MI:SS')
FROM
    sch_sismapa.tb_servidor S1
JOIN
    sch_sismapa.tb_he_norm_diurno S2 on (S2.id_servidor = S1.id)
WHERE
    S1.id_referencia = '5'
GROUP BY
    S1.id,
    S1.cd_secretaria
ORDER BY
    S1.cd_secretaria,
    S1.id;
```

Espero que tenha ficado claro minha dúvida.

Comment: Qual o tipo de dado do campo horas, interval? No resultado desejado você deseja apenas as secretarias e o total de horas correspondente de cada uma delas?

Comment: O Tipo do campo horas é real. Sim eu quero o total de horas por secretaria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente:

```
SELECT S1.cd_secretaria, to_char(SUM(S2.nr_horas)*60*'1 min'::interval, 'DD HH24:MI')
FROM sch_sismapa.tb_servidor S1 JOIN sch_sismapa.tb_he_norm_diurno S2 ON (S2.id_servidor = S1.id)  
WHERE S1.id_referencia = '5'  
GROUP BY S1.cd_secretaria  
ORDER BY S1.cd_secretaria;
```

Avalie se deseja ou não incluir `S1.id` caso `cd_secretaria` possa se repetir para diferentes `id`.

Caso o somatório nunca ultrapasse 24 horas então pode retirar o `DD` da função `to_char`.

Comment: Fantástico. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Essa maneira que você fez atende completamente minha dúvida.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar uma função de agregação como SUM():

`SELECT S1.id,S1.cd_secretaria,
        SUM(S1.id,S1.cd_secretaria), 
        to_char(to_timestamp(sum((S2.nr_horas) * 60)), 'MI:SS')
   FROM sch_sismapa.tb_servidor S1
   JOIN sch_sismapa.tb_he_norm_diurno S2 on (S2.id_servidor = S1.id)
  WHERE S1.id_referencia = '5' 
  GROUP BY S1.id,S1.cd_secretaria
  ORDER BY S1.cd_secretaria,S1.id`

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se eu entendi bem a sua pergunta, mas se você deseja recuperar a quantidade total de horas por secretaria, a coisa pode ser mais simples do que parece.

Assumindo que você tenha uma estrutura de dados como essa:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_horas
(
  id_funcionario INTEGER,
  id_secretaria INTEGER,
  nu_horas INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO tb_horas ( id_funcionario, id_secretaria, nu_horas ) VALUES
( 1233, 10, 10 ),
( 4123,  7,  5 ),
( 5545, 10, 10 ),
( 1233, 10, 10 ),
( 4123,  7,  3 );
```

A consulta seria algo do tipo:

```
SELECT
  id_secretaria,
  to_char((sum(nu_horas)) * '1 hour'::interval,'HH24:MI') AS total
FROM
  tb_horas
GROUP BY 
  id_secretaria;
```

Saída:

```
| id_secretaria | total |
|---------------|-------|
|            10 | 30:00 |
|             7 | 08:00 |
```

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/138e0/5)